# как сделать "вытягивающуюся" платформу, как панельки серии игр "portal"

Tags: python, pygame, godot

мне необходимо понять как можно реализовать свободно вытягиваемую платформу. Под словом "свободно" я имею в виду, что она может менять градус наклона любой её части как угодно и выглядело хорошо.

[image]

мне нужно, чтобы программа рассчитывала место куда вытягивать(чёрная точка), относительно центра платформы(красная точка)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот что я имел в виду как в portal'е

как мне можно это сделать?
я использую python+pygame или godot engine, поэтому вы можете ответь на питоне или на godot.

Comment: Отдаленно напоминает инверсную кинематику (Inverse Kinematic, IK).

Comment: Думаю да, напоминает. Но у меня всё ещё остался ворос: "как реализовать "вытягивание" платформы в сторону определённой точки?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 720))

def stick(x, y, angle, step):
    x += math.sin(angle) * step
    y += math.cos(angle) * step
    return x, y


class Platform:
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, orin):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.height = height
        
        if orin in ["top", "bottom"]:
            self.func = lambda angle: -angle
            self.angle = math.pi / 2
            
        elif orin in ["left", "right"]:
            self.func = lambda angle: math.pi - angle
            self.angle = 0
        else:
            raise ValueError
    
    def draw(self, win):
        x0, y0 = self.x, self.y
        x1, y1 = stick(x0, y0, self.angle, self.height / 2)
        x2, y2 = stick(x1, y1, self.func(self.angle), self.height / 2)
        
        pygame.draw.line(win, (200, 200, 200),
                            (x0, y0), (x1, y1))
        pygame.draw.line(win, (200, 200, 200),
                            (x1, y1), (x2, y2))

platform = Platform(360, 360, 360, "left")
while True:
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
    platform.draw(win)
    platform.angle += 0.01
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: В принцепе это бы помогло, если бы я не хотел сделать ещё и расчёт выпрямления платформы в зависимости от расстояния чёрной точки от центра платформы. Для вас это может показаться черезвычайно лёгким, но для меня это сложно

Comment: Хотя в какой - то мере это ответ, спасибо!